# How to Delete multiple user from table using checkbox in react and nodejs , mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, checkbox

I am handling selected users id using checkbox in the table but when i send request to server to delete them all ,  i have no idea how to handle with nodejs using mongoose. Can anyone help me?
Here is FE code:

```
const Home =()=> {
const [isChecked, setisChecked] = useState([]);
const handleDeleteUser = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/users/deleteUsers`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      body: JSON.stringify(isChecked),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  };

  const handlecheckbox = (e) => {
    const { value, checked } = e.target;
    console.log(value);
    if (checked) {
      setisChecked([...isChecked, value]);
    } else {
      setisChecked(isChecked.filter((e) => e !== value));
    }
  };
 return (
           <tbody>
              {users.map((user) => (
                <tr key={user._id}>
                  <td>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Form.Check
                        type="checkbox"
                        value={user._id}
                        checked={user.isChecked}
                        onChange={(e) => handlecheckbox(e)}
                      />
                    </Form.Group>
                  </td>
                  <td>{user._id}</td>
                  <td>{user.name}</td>
                  <td>{user.email}</td>
                  <td>{user.lastLogin}</td>
                  <td>{user.createdAt}</td>
                  <td>{user.status}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
 )
}
```

Here Nodejs code :

```
userRouter.delete('/deleteUsers', async(req,res,next)=> {
  try {
    const selectedUsers = req.body
   
  } catch (error) {
    next(error) 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `selectedUsers` in the route is an array of ids, the following line should do the trick, if you want to do hard-delete.

```js
await User.deleteMany({ _id: { $in: selectedUsers } });
```

More commonly, people want to do soft-delete where they define an `isDeleted` property on the schema as a `Boolean`, and then do the following:

```js
await User.updateMany({ _id: { $in: selectedUsers } }, { isDeleted: true });
```

Comment: Well it worked. Thank u. When i select and try to delete them , they are gone after refreshing the page  otherwise dont . can u give some tips?

Comment: Happy to help.

You need to use React so that whenever the response comes from the backend as "successful," remove the deleted users from the table, or a less-performant solution would be to reload the component once you receive the deletion response from the backend, which will re-call the API for listing users.

If this answer helped you, mark it as "Correct answer" so other people who face the same issue can find the answer quickly, thanks.

Comment: How can i remove deleted users from table when response is successs?